# Converting CvMat to CvMat* in opencv

Tags: c, opencv

Is there a way to convert cvMat to cvMAt* in opencv?
I basically have to convert a Mat object to cvMat*. So initially I convert the Mat object to a cvMat object. Now, I need to convert it into a cvMat* pointer.

Comment: To get a `T *` from a `T`, use the `&` operator. Since that's basic C, I'm assuming there's something more here.

Comment: cv::Mat and cvMat are two completely different things and you seem to be using them interchangeably. The OpenCV documentation states [cvMat is obsolete.](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=obsolete#CvMat) You should switch to using cv::Mat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an OpenCV question, it's basic C. If you're this unfamiliar with C, perhaps you should try some other solution.

That said, converting from `Object something` to `Object *something` is as easy as passing `&something` to the function you're calling.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I seemed to have tried that earlier, and it was giving an error. Now it's working. I guess earlier I was doing something else wrong.